# Django Filter Select_Related

Tags: django

When using select_related, has anyone developed a way to filter on a field in the foreign key table.

For example given these models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class AuthorExtra(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    type = models.ForeignKey(ExtraType)
    value = models.CharField(max_length = 24)
```

I would like a way to cache all of the related AuthorExtra objects of a specific type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot do this with `select_related` as it will only work for One-to-One fields or ForeignKeys. For reverse relationships like this, the development version has introduced `prefetch_related` which is exactly what you're looking for.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like 1.4 beta will be out this week, so maybe I'll upgrade.  It doesn't look like from the docs, that there is a built-in implementation to filter the prefetched records.